# vim mapping problem in vimrc file but can not find the mapping that I set

Tags: vim, neovim

I am using vim-markdown-toc plugin(successfully installed) and want to remapping some hotkey to specific function. I export this code `autocmd Filetype markdown noremapb <silent> <C-x> :GenTocMarked` to my .vimrc file. But when I type `:verbose imap <C-x>`, it shows can not find the mapping.

Can anyone tell me what's the problem about this?

and also I also want to ask how to map one hotkey to multiple function?

Answer (score 0):

```
autocmd Filetype markdown noremapb <silent> <C-x> :GenTocMarked
```

has two obvious errors:

1. `noremapb` should be `noremap`, without the `b`:

   ```
   noremap <silent> <C-x> :GenTocMarked
   ```
2. There should be a `<CR>` at the end:

   ```
   noremap <silent> <C-x> :GenTocMarked<CR>
   ```

   The right-hand-side of a mapping is a macro: since you press `<CR>` to execute the command `:GenTocMarked`, it should be present  in the RHS.

Then comes the diagnostic mistake: the `:map` command, and its non-recursive buddy `:noremap` create mappings for normal, visual, and operator-pending modes, but `:imap` prints out *insert mode* mappings so you can't really expect it to find a mapping created with `:map`.

Then comes the semantic mistake: the `re` in `noremap` is part of `nore` (short for non-recursive), not of `remap`. `<C-x>` is not a mapping so you are not "remapping" anything.

Then comes the scoping mistake: `:noremap` creates mappings for three modes, which is something you probably don't want. You should be more specific:

```
" normal mode mapping
nnoremap <silent> <C-x> :GenTocMarked<CR>
```

and, finally, the autocommand abuse mistake: there already is a built-in mechanism for sourcing filetype-specific config so there is no need to reinvent the wheel in your `vimrc`:

```
" in after/ftplugin/markdown.vim
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <C-x> :GenTocMarked<CR>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your careful answer. I may really need to study vimscript.  Would be kind of you to reexplain the `autocmd` abuse problem. You said that there already is a built-in mechanism for sourcing filetype-specific config so there is no need to reinvent the wheel in `vimrc`, what does this mean?    In which case, i should use `autocmd` command

Comment: The ideal place for keeping filetype-specific stuff is ftplugins, which are sourced by Vim automatically. Adding a `FileType` autocommand to your `vimrc` is just a pointless way to reinvent that built-in mechanism.